# How to view branch descriptions (without editing them)?

Tags: git

If one has previously entered a description for some branch `FOO`, by running

```
% git branch --edit-description FOO
```

...is there a way to view this description (other than running this same command again, i.e. other than re-editing the branch description)?

---

BTW, I've tried a couple of things, such as:

```
% git branch -av
  FOO    ca2fff9 (mumble)
* master ca2fff9 (mumble)
% git show-branch FOO
[FOO] (mumble)
```

...but no dice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see the description for all branches with:

```
git config --get-regexp branch.*.description
```

---

`git config` is what a command like [`git request-pull` does](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ace33bf991f8f6643e58a3642962ed244ba36b5b/git-request-pull.sh#L40-L49) to get the description of a branch:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>grep -nRHI description *|grep pull
git-request-pull.sh:45:         ! git config "branch.$branch_name.description" >/dev/null
```