# Git branch description

Tags: git, git-branch

I set just a simple description for my local branch and now I'd like to see it. How one can see description for a branch set by issuing `git branch --edit-description`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print branch description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058844/print-branch-description)

Comment: You can use the command form this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516895/how-to-view-branch-descriptions-without-editing-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is used for request-pull (as stated in the man-page). This has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git).

Comment: Thank you! But, is there any way to attach description to a branch that can be seen later? I'm talking about something simple like issuing `git branch` or `git notes` with certain flags and get description set previously...

Comment: I don't know of any simple way to display the branch description, unfortunately. You may parse `.git/BRANCH_DESCRIPTION`, of course, but I don't know whether this information is published to other repos with `push` or `pull`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show the branch descriptions by interrogating the repos config settings, which is where the description is stored.

I have two aliases defined, one shows all branches that have descriptions, and the second shows the description of the current HEAD branch

```
    brshow = config --get-regexp 'branch.*.description'
    brshow1 = !git config --get "branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).description"
```